# Subscriber pattern with RecoilJS (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, design-patterns, mapbox, recoiljs

I am building an app with React, TS, Mapbox, react-mapbox-gl and RecoilJS.

This is the `Dashboard` component in which I'm working:

```
import React from "react";
import PageTemplate from "../../components/PageTemplate/PageTemplate";

import ReactMapboxGl from "react-mapbox-gl";

import { CGOIncidentsMapConfig } from "./Map/CGOIncidents";
import { zoomSuscriberState, clickSuscriberState } from "../../contexts/MapContext";
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { MapEvent } from "react-mapbox-gl/lib/map-events";

const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
  accessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN ?? "",
});

const getEventHandle: (subscribers: MapEvent[]) => MapEvent = (subscribers) => (map, evt) => {
  console.log(subscribers);
  for (const event of subscribers) {
    event(map, evt);
  }
};

const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  const zoomSuscribers = useRecoilValue(zoomSuscriberState);
  const clickSuscribers = useRecoilValue(clickSuscriberState);

  console.log(zoomSuscribers);
  console.log(clickSuscribers);

  return (
    <PageTemplate>
      <Map
        style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10"
        containerStyle={{
          height: "100%",
          width: "100%",
        }}
        center={[-3.7, 40.44]}
        zoom={[5]}
        onZoom={getEventHandle(zoomSuscribers)}
        onClick={getEventHandle(clickSuscribers)}
      >
        <CGOIncidentsMapConfig />
      </Map>
    </PageTemplate>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

This is the `CGOIncidentsMapConfig` component simplified:

```
export const CGOIncidentsMapConfig: React.FC = () => {
  const [popupCoordinates, setPopupCoordinates] = useState<number[]>([-0.13235092163085938, 51.518250335096376]);
  const [isPopupVisible, setPopupVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [popopContainer, setPopupContainer] = useState("");
  const [leyend, setLeyend] = useState<{
    title: string;
    elements: {
      title: string;
      color: string;
    }[];
  }>(LEYENDS.PROVINCES);

  const onZoomMapEvent: MapEvent = (map) => {
    console.log("ZIIIM", map.getZoom());
  };

  const onMouseEnterEvent = (e: MapLayerMouseEvent) => {
    const map = e.target;
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = "pointer";
  };

  const onMouseLeaveEvent = (e: MapLayerMouseEvent) => {
    const map = e.target;
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = "";
  };

  const dismissPopup = () => {
    setPopupVisible(false);
    console.log("CIIM");
  };

  const setZoomSuscribers = useSetRecoilState(zoomSuscriberState);
  const setClickSuscribers = useSetRecoilState(clickSuscriberState);

  useEffect(() => {
    setZoomSuscribers((oldZoomSubscribers) => [...oldZoomSubscribers, onZoomMapEvent]);

    setClickSuscribers((oldClickSubscribers) => [...oldClickSubscribers, dismissPopup]);

    console.log("updated recoil");
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  console.log(isPopupVisible);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Source id={CGO_INCIDENTS_SOURCE_ID} tileJsonSource={CGO_INCIDENTS_SOURCE_OPTIONS} />
      <Layer
        id={CGO_INCIDENTS_LAYER_LAYOUT.id}
        type={CGO_INCIDENTS_LAYER_LAYOUT.type}
        sourceId={CGO_INCIDENTS_LAYER_LAYOUT.source}
        sourceLayer={CGO_INCIDENTS_LAYER_LAYOUT["source-layer"]}
        paint={CGO_INCIDENTS_LAYER_LAYOUT.paint}
        onClick={onClickEvent}
        onMouseEnter={onMouseEnterEvent}
        onMouseLeave={onMouseLeaveEvent}
      />
      {isPopupVisible && (
        <Popup coordinates={popupCoordinates} onClick={dismissPopup}>
          {popopContainer}
        </Popup>
      )}
      <Leyend title={leyend.title} elements={leyend.elements} />
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

This is my `MapContext` file in which I created the atoms:

```
import { MapEvent } from "react-mapbox-gl/lib/map-events";
import { atom } from "recoil";

export const zoomSuscriberState = atom<MapEvent[]>({ key: "zoomSuscriberState", default: [] });
export const clickSuscriberState = atom<MapEvent[]>({ key: "clickSuscriberState", default: [] });
```

As you can see, what I want to do is just to create a subscriber pattern for the onClick and onZoom events with RecoilJS. My idea with this is to separate each Mapbox layer in different components.

When the function returned by `getEventHandler` is executed, the console.log inside only displays an empty array for `zoomSuscribers` or `clickSuscribers` but what I see with the console.log into the `Dashboard` component is that both atoms have a callback function settled by the `CGOIncidentsMapConfig` component. These atoms are empty at the first render of `Dashboard` and fulfilled once `CGOIncidentsMapConfig` component has been rendered. Seems like RecoilJS updated both atoms and the `Dashboard` component, as expected.

Why the console.log inside the `getEventHandler` functions only prints an empty array? Therefore, the event are not properly executed by the subscribers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are calling the `getEventHandle` function instead of passing it to the `Map` component.

Change these lines:

```js
onZoom={getEventHandle(zoomSuscribers)}
onClick={getEventHandle(clickSuscribers)}
```

to

```js
onZoom={() => getEventHandle(zoomSuscribers)}
onClick={() => getEventHandle(clickSuscribers)}
```

Comment: First, thanks for your response.
Sadly it doesn't make sense: `onZoom` and `onClick` are properties that need a function with two parameters: map and event.

The change that you propouse should be something like this:
```
onZoom={(map,evt) => getEventHandle(zoomSuscribers)(map,evt)}
onClick={(map,evit) => getEventHandle(clickSuscribers)(map,evt)}
``` 
Sadly this won't fix my problem because it's the same.

Thanks anyway for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

The solution whas with `useRecoilCallback`:

```
import React from "react";
import PageTemplate from "../../components/PageTemplate/PageTemplate";

import ReactMapboxGl from "react-mapbox-gl";

import { CGOIncidentsMapConfig } from "./Map/CGOIncidents";
import { zoomSuscriberState, clickSuscriberState } from "../../contexts/MapContext";
import { useRecoilCallback, useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { MapEvent } from "react-mapbox-gl/lib/map-events";

const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
  accessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN ?? "",
});

const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  const onZoom: MapEvent = useRecoilCallback(({ snapshot }) => async (map, evt) => {
    const subs = await snapshot.getPromise(zoomSuscriberState);
    for (const event of subs) {
      event(map, evt);
    }
  });

  const onClick: MapEvent = useRecoilCallback(({ snapshot }) => async (map, evt) => {
    const subs = await snapshot.getPromise(clickSuscriberState);
    for (const event of subs) {
      event(map, evt);
    }
  });

  return (
    <PageTemplate>
      <Map
        style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10"
        containerStyle={{
          height: "100%",
          width: "100%",
        }}
        center={[-3.7, 40.44]}
        zoom={[5]}
        onZoom={onZoom}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <CGOIncidentsMapConfig />
      </Map>
    </PageTemplate>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```